# Export Jenkins reports to Excel

Tags: excel, jenkins

I am new to Jenkins.  We have jenkins kicking off  several builds every night and I want to pull the failures out from all builds and put them into excel (or google dox version of excel).  Is there any smart way to do this?  Thanks

Comment: why do you need this? You have so nice options on jenkins, like RSS or directly on the Jenkins page with some nice diagrams...

Comment: Agree with Henry. Have a look at the plugin list (https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Plugins). The plugin's there cater for almost all standard wishes and several very specific ones. It also helps to frequently have a look at the list for new plugins.

Comment: Reason is to ollate failures from a number of builds onto one page and to be able to add additional information. In Excel, each failure can go into a row and extra data can easily be put into additional columns.  Not saying this is the best way - just looking for advice. Thx.

Answer (score 2):

Now that Jenkins integrates Groovy for Pipeline builds, or just plain Groovy scripts, it is straightforward to write some Groovy code that uses the Apache POI libraries to create a genuine Excel spreadsheet with colors, fonts, highlights or whatever you need.

Answer (score 1):

Create a script and use it as a *Post Steps* build phase with an option *Run regardless of build result* checked. The script, which can be anything, can push data after every build to CSV file, and if you use PowerShell - to the Excel file as well. Damn, if you use Google Docs SDK you can easily add data to GDoc Spreadsheet or do something else. No limits here.