# How to view the excel reports in Jenkins?

Tags: java, jenkins

In my code I am using Excel for reporting format. Is there any possibility to see(To download or google sheets) the same excel report in Jenkins?

Comment: If the report is created during the build, your could archive it as an artifcat. Documentation for `Jenkinsfile`: https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/tour/tests-and-artifacts/

For regular pipelines have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5821545/archive-the-artifacts-in-jenkins

Comment: Can't you put it in the workspace? you can download it from there whenever you want. Or in the shell block, you can call google sheet api to upload the sheet. A lot of discussion is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8913140/export-jenkins-reports-to-excel