# Is there any specific ways to print the parameters after the Jenkins pipeline run

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, devops

I want to print the parameters like timestamp,user and the project name after the pipeline is completed and it will print in a Excel or csv format. Is there any specific plugin for this?
I have tried finding but it is all for freestyle projects.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Export Jenkins reports to Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8913140/export-jenkins-reports-to-excel)

Comment: The answers were not helpful. The explanations are not clear enough.@LaurynasLazauskas

Comment: Can you please help me out with  a brief answer